# How to compare more than one dataframe and return less than or equal

Tags: python, list, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have two data frames that i would like to compare either less than or equal to a certain number. For example, i  would like df1 to find -10 or + 10 in df2 and return the Ids and range from both data frames.

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
x = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
x["Range"] = x.ID_y - x.ID_x
x = x[x.Range.abs() <= 10]

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    ID_x  ID_y  Range
4     98    89     -9
5     98   100      2
9     98    92     -6
15    92    82    -10
16    92    89     -3
17    92   100      8
21    92    92      0
25    86    77     -9
27    86    82     -4
28    86    89      3
32    86    81     -5
33    86    92      6
37    77    77      0
39    77    82      5
44    77    81      4
85    79    77     -2
87    79    82      3
88    79    89     10
92    79    81      2
```

Comment: how do i get rid of x ,y and rename to something else. Other that it this code works. Thanks

Comment: @Chris You can do afterwards `x = x.rename(columns={'ID_x':'df1', 'ID_y':'df2'})`